# How to devise destroy session and sign out from controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

Devise destroy session and sign out from controller?

```
if something_is_not_kosher
  # 1. log this event, 2. send notice
  redirect_to destroy_user_session_path and return
end
```

Also tried:

```
if something_is_not_kosher
 # 1. log this event, 2. send notice
  redirect_to controller: 'devise/sessions', action: 'destroy', method: :delete and return
end
```

Error is `No route matches [GET] "/users/sign_out"` but I'm explicitly setting method: :delete in example 2. Maybe devise has a method? `current_user.sign_out` and tried sign_out(current_user) which also don't work? Thanks for the help.

rake routes:

```
        new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)         devise/sessions#new
            user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)         devise/sessions#create
    destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)        devise/sessions#destroy
           user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)        devise/passwords#create
       new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)    devise/passwords#new
      edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)   devise/passwords#edit
                         PATCH  /users/password(.:format)        devise/passwords#update
                         PUT    /users/password(.:format)        devise/passwords#update
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)          users/registrations#cancel
       user_registration POST   /users(.:format)                 users/registrations#create
   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)         users/registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)            users/registrations#edit
                         PATCH  /users(.:format)                 users/registrations#update
                         PUT    /users(.:format)                 users/registrations#update
                         DELETE /users(.:format)                 users/registrations#destroy
```

Comment: Do you have `devise_for :users` in your `routes.rb`?

Comment: Yes of course I do @Peter

Comment: Can you run `rake routes` and give us the output?

Comment: Try `redirect_to destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete`

Comment: sure, Routes added @richsinn

Comment: @Peter I tried that ... error: `No route matches [GET] "/users/sign_out"`

Comment: Thanks for the help guys.. I answered it below.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So I ended up solving this by creating a custom signout route

```
  devise_scope :user do
    get '/signout', to: 'devise/sessions#destroy', as: :signout
  end
```

and in my controller I have:

```
if something_is_not_kosher
  redirect_to signout_path and return
end
```

Answer (score 20):

Why don't you just use devise's built-in [`sign_out_and_redirect(current_user)`](http://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Controllers/Helpers#sign_out_and_redirect-instance_method) method?

Comment: Maybe I was using it wrong but it didn't work for me. Thanks anyway

Comment: I still suggest giving this another try instead of exposing a new route to sign out via get.

Comment: While this would have been nice, it didn't work for me, guessing it's not available in our current version. I had to use dddd1919's solution, `sign_out current user` then `redirect_to` the home page.

Answer (score 6):

`destroy_user_session_path(@user)` is sign out path for user, but it must requst with `DELETE` method. `redirect_to` method will tell broswer to request another path, but broswer just can request with `GET` method.
So if you want to let user to sign out, you must set a sign out form with `DELETE` method or with AJAX request to let user sign out but not with `redirect_to` function.

If you just want to destroy user session, use `sign_out @user` is ok.

Answer (score 3):

Just in case someone can't use it directly.

```
        <% if user_signed_in? %>
        <li><%= link_to "Logout", destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete %></li>
        <% else %>
        <li><%= link_to "Sign up now!",  new_user_registration_path%></li>
        <% end %>
```

Comment: If we do that we send a request to `users/sign_out` with the method of `GET`, which doesn't exist in our route path. Even ``:method => :delete`` method doesn't help here