# Issue regarding automatic logout from all active sessions across all browser in rails 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, devise, logout, ruby-on-rails-2

I have an existing rails 2 app where I need to introduce the following feature of automatic logout from all session of the logged in user after successful password reset. The devise gem is used over here.

Went through the following solution 
[Logout from ActiveAdmin destroy other sessions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33502026/logout-from-activeadmin-destroy-other-sessions)

But it did not work for me. I am getting the following error and the server gets stopped working.

undefined method `sign_out_all_scopes=' for Devise:Module (NoMethodError)

Probably devise gem has this particular facility for rails>=3.1

So, please help to figure out this problem and to implement this functionality on a rails 2 app.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

For logging out of the application and destroying the user session there is a devise's built-in method `sign_out_and_redirect(current_user)`. Can you please check if this is working in rails 2. For further help, you can check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25858606/how-to-devise-destroy-session-and-sign-out-from-controller).

Comment: @Abhradip can you please tell me which devise version you are using.

Comment: devise version 1.0.11 and rails version 2.3.18

Comment: I think destroy_user_session_path will do the trick as you can check routes.

Comment: Will it destroy all open sessions of the current user across all browser?

Comment: destroy_user_session_path is not working for me. Its not even throwing any error.

Comment: @Abhradip did you find the answer to this? I am also trying to invalidate all user sessions in all browsers on user logout, but there doesn't seem to a be a straight-forward approach for this